# Can you shape a magnet and how would it effect its field

Tags: electromagnetism

Long story short im playing with mental designs of an electric motor and I'm not sure on some things regarding magmets/magnrtic materials and my designs are in flux do to these variables. I'm wondering one if you can put a "blade" along an auger that holds a current to act as an electromagnet basically build a case to hold the blades n wires or if youd have to shape a magnetic material into the full auger. This idea is kind of like the wind towers that spin like a cyclone instead of the air making the rack spin I'm wondrring if you can force rotation with a coil around it. My idea is basically put the auger in a coil launcher set up so that when a current goes through the coil it spins the auger.

Comment: A drawing might help us understand what you are asking. Also, please consider cleaning up the spelling and such.

Comment: Shortest explanation I can come up with is a coil launcher used to spin an auger that has a magnetic blade I have a very rough sketch in gravity sketch on VR but bein I have no sschooling after basics I'm not sure how to pull it off. Basically I'm thinking replace piston with augers on axles the coils magnetic propulsion would be used to push up on the blades causing circular motion due to the blade angles. If anyone has info on how I can upload the quick sketch ill add that

Comment: I have no idea what a “coil launcher” is.

Comment: Coilgun or motor. Uses the magnetic field generated in a coil to push objects. Basically the catapults of the rail gun family. Originally I had thought of a puck on the end of a rod for a cramshaft but I think a magnet cork screw n driveshaft maybe more efficient n harnessing the push from the induced field traveling the coil

Comment: Are you thinking of turning an auger with an electric motor? Fine. If so, what is the rest about?

Answer (score 0):

To help with your intuition you can imagine any form, filled with tiny ball magnets. Each small piece of magnet can have its own orientation of the field. There is no rule that says that macroscopic magnetic field has to be of a particular direction such as axial or radial, reason for it is pirely convinience of making such magnets.

With your 'spinning if magnetic field is present' closest analogue is this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homopolar_motor

It is one of the most unusual motor. While reading about how it works, and what changes to it stop it from workinf, you will understand more about your model too.

In short - stationary magnetic field doesnt make a 'whirl', it makes a 'well'. Magnetic field has magnitude and direction, so intuitively it seems that it can be made in a way similar to a whirl in a bathtub, using magnets at an angle inside or outside the whirl. But in practice such arrangemenr makes similar magnetic field that a radially magnetized ring would make. Difference in intuition and practice is hard to pin down, but probably this will help:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_magnetism

To check your model for correctness you need to draw a closed loop and make sure that magnetic field cancels out within this loop. A well consist of closed loop, a ring. A whirl consist of open lines, that dont cancel out. This contradicts the Gauss law and shows that model is not working.